# React-Navigation: Navigation goback()

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

SCREEN - X - Children (SCREEN A, SCREEN B)

SCREEN - A - Children (SCREEN A, SCREEN B, SCREEN C)

I have navigated from **X -> A -> A**. Here Screen data has been rendered from **Redux Store** for *SCREEN - A*. When i **goBack()** the previous screen is not getting rendered. When navigating back in React Navigation prev screen is not getting rendered. Because data required for first SCREEN-A has been overridden by the second rendered SCREEN-A. How to achieve this?

Info: React Navigation V2 without Redux Integration.

Comment: why A is both screen and child? even is it the child of itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can manupilate the history with `StackActions` and `NavigationActions`.

For example:

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'X' }),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'A' }),
  ],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

Then you can go back as usual.

EDIT:

I might have misunderstood your question. If you are using 2 navigators which has several screens in it, you should combine them with a `createSwitchNavigator` to have a single navigation to get skip the parent navigator.